# how to use websocket in nativescript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript

can someone help me on how to use websocket in nativescript
Am using vuejs in nativescript and trying to fetch data with ws.

I will really appreciate it if someone assist me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the **nativescript-websockets** or **nativescript-socketio** plugins?

Comment: yes i did, It was comes up with an error when running and am testing the nativescript- vue framework. If yours works can you assist me with your source code. Thank